# Delphi работа с COM портом и микроконтроллером

Tags: delphi, winapi, микроконтроллеры, com-порт

Есть проект в котором общаются программа на Delphi и микроконтроллер. При этом взаимодействие с COM портом на Delphi организовано с помощью WinApi.

При запуске программы запускается поиск доступных портов, и затем в каждый из них отправляется определенная последовательность символов для идентификации устройства, т.е. если после принятой последовательности, если на данный порт поступит другая последовательность данных от устройства, то мы нашли необходимый порт и можем начинать работу.

Но, есть проблема: при запуске программы из среды разработки Delphi7, программа отрабатывает нормально (хотя иногда устройство не находится, и приходится перезапускать прогу). А вот если же запускать отдельно exe файл, прога практически никогда не может идентифицировать устройство.

В связи с этим вопрос: как можно улучшить (или вообще переделать мой протокол) для того чтобы все работало нормально? Или проще: каким образом сделать так, чтобы после отправки сообщения в порт, основной поток подождал некоторое время, а затем сравнил флаг "открытости" порта?

```
    //Get Computer COM-Ports
  function TForm1.GetComPort:BOOL;
    var
      ctrl_char:Char;   //Контрольный байт
      Str:String;
      i:integer;
      CommList: TStringList;
  begin
    CommList:=TStringList.Create;
    ctrl_char:='F';             // Ctrl-char for
    Str:='F';                  // starting connection
    isOpenHandle:=False;        // Down the Flag of working COM
    FillCommList(CommList);    //Заполняем список портов

    for i:=1 to (CommList.Count-1) do begin   //Отправляем последовательность в доступные порты
            try
              StartService(CommList[i]);      //Стартуем COM порт 
            except
              on E: Exception do
                begin
                  result:=false;
                  continue;
                end;
             end;

          try
            WriteStrToPort(Str,ctrl_char);  //Trying write to port
          except
            on E:Exception do
              begin
                result:=false;
                continue;
              end;
           end;

             Application.ProcessMessages;

              if(isOpenHandle=True) then   //Флаг о том, что был получен ответный сигнал от МК 
                                           //If port Opened, then Close it
               begin                       //Break the loop, and returning true
                   CloseComm();
                   Result:=true;
                   CommNum:=CommList[i];
                   break;
               end

              else
               begin
                  Result:=false;
               end;

          end;
      end;


 function TForm1.FillCommList( List : Tstrings ): integer;   //Функция заполнения доступных портов
      var
        ComName: string;
        i: integer;
        pPath : pchar;
        Size : Cardinal;
        NewItem, toitem: TMenuItem;
        Str:String;
      begin
        List.Clear();               //Чистим список
        pPath := Stralloc( 256 );   
          try                       
            for i := 1 to 99 do
              begin
                pPath[0] := #0;
                ComName := 'COM' + inttostr( i );
                QueryDosDevice( pchar( ComName), pPath, Size );  
                                                                 
                                                                 
                if CompareText( pPath, '' ) <> 0 then            
                  begin
                    List.AddObject( ComName, pointer( i ) );
                    NewItem:=TMenuItem.Create(NewItem);
                    NewItem.Caption:=(ComName);
                    NewItem.OnClick:=NewItemClick;
                    COM1.Add(NewItem);
            end;
          end;
          finally
            strdispose( pPath );                                 
          end;
        result := List.Count;
      end;
```

Далее привожу код для работы с COM портом, который идет во втором потоке

```
      //Starting the procedure interviewing the port
  Procedure TCommThread.Execute;
    Begin
    if isConnected = false then    //Запуск синхронного потока для первого подключения
      begin
          Synchronize(QueryPort);
      end
    else
      begin
     {Execute}
      Repeat
        QueryPort;
        // Will work until Terminated
        Until Terminated;
      end;

    End;  {Execute}

Procedure TCommThread.QueryPort;
    Var
      Ovr : TOverlapped;
      Events : array[0..1] of THandle;
      MyBuff:Array[0..63] Of Char;              //Buffer for readed inf
      ByteReaded:Dword;                          //Number of readed bytes
      tmp,tmp1:String;
      stop_charPos, ctrl_charPos4:integer;
      flag:Bool;

    Begin {QueryPort}
      flag:=false;
      //Read Buffer from Com-port
      FillChar(Ovr,SizeOf(TOverlapped),0);
      Ovr.hEvent:=CreateEvent(nil,TRUE,FALSE,#0);
      Events[0] := Ovr.hEvent;

        If Not ReadFile(hPort,MyBuff,SizeOf(MyBuff),ByteReaded,@Ovr) Then
          Begin {Error with readed files}
            //Error, close all and exit
            SysErrorMessage(GetLastError);
            Exit;
            CloseHandle(Ovr.hEvent);
          End;{Error with readed files}

      //Data recieved
      If ByteReaded>0 Then
        Begin {ByteReaded>0}
        //Making string from recieved buffer
              tmp:=string(MyBuff);

      ctrl_charPos3:=0;
      tmp1:=tmp;
                                            //Parsing recieved string
      stop_charPos :=AnsiPos('#',tmp);       //Stop char
      ctrl_charPos4:=AnsiPos('G',tmp);      //Ctrl-char for connecting protocol

              //Connecting protocol
            if (ctrl_charPos4<>0) then
                  begin
                      SendMessage(fmMain.Handle,cmRxByte,4,Integer(0));
                     //Sending COM-start request to the main form
            end;
      End; {ByteReaded>0}
End; {QueryPort}


  //Close COM-Port       
  function CloseComm : boolean;
    begin
     SetCommMask(hPort,0);
     //Close handle
     PurgeComm(hPort,PURGE_TXABORT or PURGE_RXABORT or PURGE_TXCLEAR or PURGE_RXCLEAR);
     CloseHandle(hPort);
     CommThread.Free;                    //Thread free
     Result := True;
  end;


//=====================================CloseComm=================================


//******************************************************************************


//====================================StartService==============================


  //Start COM-port service
  function StartService(ComName:String):Bool;
    Begin {StartService}
  ComPort:=ComName;
            if  InitPort = true then         //Initialization of port
              begin
                StartComThread;             //Starting COM thread
                Result:=true;
              end
            else
              begin                        //If unsuccesfull(error,connected with portNum), then
                PurgeComm(hPort,PURGE_TXABORT or PURGE_RXABORT or PURGE_TXCLEAR or PURGE_RXCLEAR);
                CloseHandle(hPort);        //Closing and deleting object
                Result:=false;
              end;
    End;  {StartService}
```

Процедуру инициализации не привожу, в ней ошибок не должно быть
И последняя часть: прием сообщения от второго потока в главном:

```
 procedure TForm1.RecivBytes(var Msg: TMessage);   //Messages from second thread
       var
        s:PChar;
          begin
              case Msg.WParam of

                 //Connecting protocol
                 4: begin
                       isOpenHandle:=true;
                       Application.ProcessMessages;
                    end;
              end;
          end;
```

Comment: А почему бы вам не задействовать таймер TTimer?

Comment: `Synchronize(QueryPort);` такой поток не имеет смысла - всё выполняется в главном потоке. Кроме того, не гарантируется, что вся посылка от порта придёт в одном сообщении, нельзя на это рассчитывать, нужно копить данные.

Comment: Он был добавлен чисто для проверки, но да, результатов никаких не показал.
Если по дебагеру смотреть, то посылку я получаю полностью.
Более того, для этого я ввел таймер, про который мне написали выше, для того чтобы посылка 100 проц пришла, однако никаких видимых результатов это не дало

Comment: Так ответ приходит?

Comment: Ответ приходит (сужу по светодиоду на плате и по дебаггеру. Однако если вне среды разработки запускать, то программа не стартует (хотя светодиодики тоже мигают)

Comment: Ну надо же локализовать проблему. Сделайте вывод принятой строки (`tmp)`) в консоль или куда-нибудь там, если программа оконная

Answer (score 0):

Короче, все оказалось до боли просто:

В моем изначальном коде программа просто не всегда успевала прочитать контрольную последовательность, идущую от МК, и соответственно, протокол соединения нарушался.

Поэтому была добавлена следующая задержка:

```
procedure del_time(d : integer); // Delay in ms
var
  a: integer;
begin
  a := GetTickCount;
  repeat
  until (GetTickCount - a) >= d;
end;
```

в код:

```
for i:=1 to (CommList.Count-1) do begin
    try
      StartService(CommList[i]);
    except
      on E: Exception do
        begin
          result:=false;
          continue;
        end;
     end;

    WriteStrToPort(Str,ctrl_char);  //Trying write to port

       del_time(1000);               //Таймер

       Application.ProcessMessages;

      if(isOpenHandle=True) then    //If port Opened, then Close it
       begin                       //Break the loop, and returning true
           CloseComm;
           Result:=true;
           CommNum:=CommList[i];
           break;
       end

      else
       begin
          Result:=false;
       end;

  end;
end;
```

По окончании работы таймера вызывается процедура `Application.ProcessMessages`, "читающая сообщения" от второго потока, где гарантировано уже будет необходимая мне последовательность.

Ну и плюсом были исправлены незначительные недочеты в протоколе передачи со стороны МК. И совокупность этих факторов решила проблему.

Comment: Охохонюшки.... Не хотите использовать какую-либо готовую библиотеку для асинхронной работы с портом? Костыли вам ещё могут аукнуться.

Comment: На самом деле нет такого желания, на данный момент все устраивает и с WinApi функциями. Да и кто знает, может и с библиотекой проблемы будут

Comment: Программирования на `sleep()`ах... это ад! Там в API есть `GetEvent()` (за точность названия не ручаюсь, очень давно с WinAPI не имел дела), вот её используйте, а не таймеры с непонятными задержками.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за совет, попробую заменить